# Application that tracks all locations

Tags: ios, iphone-app, tracking

What application tracks all locations that I visit?

I would like it to work in the background.

Ideally it would ignore me driving.

Comment: How would your application be different than option in to iOS system services that can track frequent locations?

Comment: @bmike It would list more.  I'm assuming you are talking about this https://www.iphonefaq.org/archives/973297

Comment: Yes - the system services per https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT203033 can track and name "frequent locations" but it often requires a couple visits and it also self cleans historical data so that only a limited view is available on the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [<sub><sub><sub>[image]</sub></sub></sub> Google Maps](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/google-maps-gps-navigation/id585027354?mt=8&at=1001lwpF)

Google Maps provides Location History when permitted to run in the background. This creates a timeline of all the places you've visited, available to view in the app or at [google.com/maps/timeline](https://www.google.com/maps/timeline).

> **Make your timeline**
>
> To make your timeline, you'll need to turn on your Location and Location History. Google uses your location, search, and browsing info to make your timeline.
>
> 1. On your iPhone or iPad, open the Google Maps app Google Maps.
> 2. Tap Menu Menu and then Settings.
> 3. Tap Personal content and then scroll down to "Location settings."
> 4. Make sure you see "Location Services is on." If you don’t, tap Location Services is not set to always and then Location and then Always.
>
> **See where you've been**
>
> 1. On your iPhone or iPad, open the Google Maps app Google Maps.
> 2. Tap Menu Menu and then Your timeline Timeline.
> 3. To see another day or month, tap Show calendar Event and then swipe left or right and tap a day.

[View or edit your timeline](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6258979?co=GENIE.Platform%3DiOS&hl=en&oco=1)

Answer (score 1):

### [<sub><sub><sub>[image]</sub></sub></sub> Life Cycle](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/life-cycle-track-your-time/id1064955217?mt=8&at=1001lwpF)

I've had a great experience with Life Cycle, which is the only app I've found to track location without consuming cellular data, crucial for me on a limited data plan. You can give locations names to help identification in reports, or the building names from maps are assigned automatically. Driving (or other travel) is automatically accounted for in a separate section independent of visits to places.

> Life Cycle automatically keeps track of your time and presents your life sorted into slices. It shows you your daily activities, places you go, and who you spend time with. Whether you’re just curious of how your time is spent or looking to make a change, Life Cycle is your daily companion, providing you with all the information and insights you need. What’s more - it uses only 1% of your phone’s battery while it seamlessly does the work.
>
> [image]

Answer (score 0):

[Penteract Where Was I](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/penteract-where-was-i/id1481252938) does that.

It does not, however, ignore driving.

[image]